# Interface and implemented methods

Tags: java, api, interface, abstract-class

I have here a question. Based on Java 7 API Collection is an interface, but yet it comes with some concrete methods, such as size(). I don't get it, how is that interface contains implemented methods. It makes sense if that was an abstract class.
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Collection is an interface, but yet it comes with some concrete methods, such as size().

This is not true. An *interface* as you already know just defines the contract and leaves the implementation to classes implementing it. If you're referring to something like

```
Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Size of the collection is: " + collection.size());
```

Please note that the `size()` implementation was provided by the `ArrayList` not `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Collection` does not have implemented methods, it is an interface. Here's the declaration of the `size` method:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this collection.  If this collection
 * contains more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
 * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this collection
 */
int size();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concrete implementation for any methods. The method you are referring to, `size` also doesn't have any concrete implementation.

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this collection.  If this collection
 * contains more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
 * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this collection
 */
int size();
```

Comment: So, then the method size() is an abstract method. Once you implement Collection interface you need to override the abstract method, don't you? But there are more such methods.

Comment: _But there are more such methods._ You mean methods with implementations? It can't be right? Interface (in general) can't have methods with implementations.. By default all methods in interface are `abstract`

Comment: Once you implement that interface you inherit those methods. Once that is done you can perform operations on object which is inherently a Collection. That fact bothers me cause those methods are not annotated as abstract.